# Get images only with relative path | Regular expresion

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract images that have the relative path `('/folder/image.jpg', 'someimage.png')` from a string, but not the absolute path `(https://www.example.com/abc.jpg)` and then push all the images in some array.

**Current array:** 
`["123.png", "abc.jpg", "xyz.jpg", "http://example.com/abc.jpg", "https://example.com/xyz.jpg", "popcorn.png"]`

**Expected array:** `["123.png", "abc.jpg", "xyz.jpg", "popcorn.png"]`

TEST: https://codepen.io/Ashish9342/pen/qLwWYz?editors=0011

```js
var content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <img style="height:10px" src="123.png"/> adipiscing elit. Praesent sed orci vitae nulla ultricies vehicula. Donec ex arcu, ultricies at nisl et, convallis lobortis nisl. Pellentesque aliquet luctus mollis. <img src="abc.jpg"/> Ut vehicula, lectus et iaculis molestie, est purus dignissim magna, sit amet tincidunt quam ante varius neque. Pellentesque quis ligula <img class="fantom" src="xyz.jpg"/> in risus efficitur ullamcorper. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis porta, eros at sollicitudin viverra, nisl lectus dapibus erat, id rutrum augue augue sed lectus. <img src="http://example.com/abc.jpg"/> Nullam felis augue, placerat vel mattis et, viverra sit amet elit. Cras pulvinar iaculis massa, sed consectetur <img src="https://example.com/xyz.jpg"/> ligula luctus non. Donec vel augue mattis tellus rutrum ultricies et suscipit  <img src="popcorn.png" alt="pop corn"/> erat.'

function getRelativePathImages(content) {
  if (content && content.search('<img')) {
    const urls = [];
    let m;
    const rex = /<img[^>]+src="([^">]+)/g;
    // const rex = /<img[^>]+src="([^http">]+)/g;

    while (m = rex.exec(content)) {
      if (urls.indexOf(m[1]) < 0) {
        urls.push(m[1]);
      }
    }
    console.log(urls);
  }
}

getRelativePathImages(content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have this negative lookahead in your regex `(?!http)` after `src="` which will reject any url starting with `http` and change your regex to

```
/<img[^>]+src="(?!http)([^">]+)/g
```

```js
var content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <img style="height:10px" src="123.png"/> adipiscing elit. Praesent sed orci vitae nulla ultricies vehicula. Donec ex arcu, ultricies at nisl et, convallis lobortis nisl. Pellentesque aliquet luctus mollis. <img src="abc.jpg"/> Ut vehicula, lectus et iaculis molestie, est purus dignissim magna, sit amet tincidunt quam ante varius neque. Pellentesque quis ligula <img class="fantom" src="xyz.jpg"/> in risus efficitur ullamcorper. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis porta, eros at sollicitudin viverra, nisl lectus dapibus erat, id rutrum augue augue sed lectus. <img src="http://example.com/abc.jpg"/> Nullam felis augue, placerat vel mattis et, viverra sit amet elit. Cras pulvinar iaculis massa, sed consectetur <img src="https://example.com/xyz.jpg"/> ligula luctus non. Donec vel augue mattis tellus rutrum ultricies et suscipit  <img src="popcorn.png" alt="pop corn"/> erat.'

function getRelativePathImages(content) {
  if (content && content.search('<img')) {
    const urls = [];
    let m;
    const rex = /<img[^>]+src="(?!http)([^">]+)/g;
    // const rex = /<img[^>]+src="([^http">]+)/g;

    while (m = rex.exec(content)) {
      if (urls.indexOf(m[1]) < 0) {
        urls.push(m[1]);
      }
    }
    console.log(urls);
  }
}

getRelativePathImages(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex, if paths you don't want start with `http`. Just use `startsWith` method:

```
s = "http://example.com/abc.jpg";
if(!s.startsWith("http")){
  // add s to you array of URLs
}
```